# Install Dotnet Core SDK 3.1 in Buildroot?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, buildroot

I have searched for a long time but have not found any instructions or help in the whole WorldWideWeb how to install the DotNet Core SDK 3.1 on a buildroot for 64Bit systems.

Unfortunately DotNet is not available in the menuconfig entry, so you have to install and use it manually.

Does anyone already have DotNet Core installed on a buildroot and can show me how to add the package manually to buildroot ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Linux installation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux)? With buildroot you're creating *your own* distribution, with your own package manager etc so it's impossible to find instructions that match what your choices are. You can check the tools used for various Linux distributions that are similar to your own and use them

Comment: Well i fail to install .net sdk i want to integrate it into buildroot so that when i want to build buildroot with "make" it automatically integrates dotnet into buildroot and i can just use the image. So I want to have dotnet in the buildroot image automatically.

Comment: Fail how? What did you try, what error did you get, which package managers are you using? You're asking people to guess not just what you did, but even what OS you use - because it's your own custom build

Answer (score 1):

I have just made a package for Buildroot you are looking for. Please take a look at my post to Buildroot's mail list fore more details and caveats:
http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2020-August/289140.html

Basically, you need to create new directory package/dotnet-runtime and place three files there: Config.in, dotnet-runtime.hash and dotnet-runtime.mk (I am using external tree as described here: https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#outside-br-custom). These are small text files, so I copy the content here.

- Config.in:

```
comment "dotnet-runtime needs a toolchain w/ glibc and threads"
        depends on !BR2_TOOLCHAIN_USES_GLIBC

config BR2_PACKAGE_DOTNET_RUNTIME
    bool "dotnet-runtime"
    depends on BR2_TOOLCHAIN_USES_GLIBC
    depends on BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_LIBZLIB
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_LIBCURL
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_ICU
    help
      .NET Core 3.1 Runtime (v3.1.7) - Linux ARM32 binaries

      https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1
```

- dotnet-runtime.hash (just one line)

```
sha512 a586ed88cebbef298cda04c94e1809017800abea50668e18bcf27c3aa1ca114bb16963bcdcc4fd535288838120cba52966d594ef395bb8fac11693f64c97ccc1 dotnet-runtime-3.1.7-linux-arm.tar.gz
```

- dotnet-runtime.mk

```
################################################################################
#
# dotnet-runtime
#
################################################################################
DOTNET_RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.1.7
DOTNET_RUNTIME_SITE = https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/69984653-402e-442c-9588-eb92560d0fce/5ad7995a09334dd2ee56f00fb6dc0521
DOTNET_RUNTIME_SOURCE = dotnet-runtime-$(DOTNET_RUNTIME_VERSION)-linux-arm.tar.gz
DOTNET_RUNTIME_LICENSE = MIT
DOTNET_RUNTIME_LICENSE_FILES = LICENSE.txt

# Runtime could be installed in the global location [/usr/share/dotnet] and
# will be picked up automatically.
# As alternative, it is possible to use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable
# to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in
# [/etc/dotnet/install_location] 
# This script will install runtime to
# /usr/share/dotnet-runtime-$(DOTNET_RUNTIME_VERSION)
define DOTNET_RUNTIME_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    cp -R $(@D) $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/share/
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

After selecting all dependencies, the package should be visible in menuconfig. This package is not 100% universal (only for 32-bit ARM) but should be easy to adapt for other use-cases. Just change download links and hash for 64-bit version. Please refer to the mailing list post I mentioned above for more details.